# What are the consequences of app transferring from one Apple developer account to another account?

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, apple-developer, app-transfer

I want to transfer an app from one Apple developer account to another account. I know that transferring app from one account to another is possible if the app satisfies some conditions.

I have some questions regarding the app transferring process:

1. Will the bundle ID of the app in the new account be same?
2. Can the bundle id of the app in the new account be changed later?
3. Is there any need of creating provisional profile and distribution certificate for the new app?

Please help me with your valuable answer.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can mail to Apple support for get the official answer

Answer (score 1):

1. The bundle ID will stay the same, that's the point of the transfer.
2. The bundle ID can never be changed, not even on the current account.
3. The app continues to work normally, but if you want to upload a new version, new certificates will need to be created on the account, since only the bundle ID is transferred.

Take a look at the [official documentation](https://help.apple.com/app-store-connect/#/deved688524f) for more info.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This really helps.

Comment: You're welcome. Please consider upvoting or accepting this answer if you consider it to be the correct one. :)